# jQuery not appending the entire generated HTML (td tag)

Tags: jquery, html

I have this code:

```
var priceTextField = $("<td>").append(
  $("<input>")
  .addClass("form-control input-sm")
  .attr("type", "text")
  .attr("placeholder", "Input something or delete me!")
);
```

And when appending it by...

```
var priceDataRow = $("<tr>").append(
  priceTextField.clone().find("input").addClass("text-quantity")
).append(
  priceTextField.clone().find("input").addClass("text-price")
).append(
  $("<td>").append(
    $("<button>")
    .addClass("btn btn-danger btn-sm btn-block delete-btn")
    .attr("type", "button")
    .text("Delete")
  )
);
```

The `<td>` wrappers from the priceTextField clones are not appearing. However, the button `<td>` wrappers are.

Example Output:

```
<tr>
  <input class="form-control input-sm text-quantity" type="text" placeholder="Input something or delete me!" value="444">
  <input class="form-control input-sm text-price" type="text" placeholder="Input something or delete me!" value="44">
  <td>
    <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm btn-block delete-btn" type="button">Delete</button>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Have I missed something obvious? If someone could point me in the right direction that would be much appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: I think, you are appending the input field, inside an another input field. So how this will work?

Comment: Sorry @Samir, I've tried to format the code as best as possible, though I'm fairly sure I've done the `append()`s correctly. The first code block effectively wraps the input in the `<td>` tag, then the second block adds two clones one after the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you did : `priceTextField.clone().find("input").addClass("text-quantity")` you actually took the input field and appended that. Not the `<td>`. Because you used `find()`

https://api.jquery.com/find/

> **Description**: Get the *descendants* of each element in the current set of
>   matched elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or element.

What you need is `end()` so that you can pick the `<td>` itself.

https://api.jquery.com/end/

> **Description:** End the most recent filtering operation in the current
>   chain and return the set of matched elements to its previous state.

Comment: Ahh yes, thank you! I understand. I just tested to see that `end()` returns it to the `clone()` method as opposed to the original variable, as it wasn't in the documentation. So works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`.end()`](http://api.jquery.com/end)

```
priceTextField.clone().find("input").addClass("text-quantity").end()
```

Comment: Used this - was perfect. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You are only appending the input elements. This is how jQuery works:

This first example returns a clone of the "td" that you created before.

```
priceTextField.clone()
```

But when you do this the "input" element will be returned.

```
priceTextField.clone().find("input")
```

What you need to do is save this in a variable first like this:

```
var priceDataRow = $("<tr>");
var clonedTd = priceTextField.clone();
clonedTd.find("input").addClass("text-quantity");
$(priceDataRow).append(clonedTd);
```

Comment: I ended up using @himanshu-tyagi 's solution, but thank you for the reply!

Comment: @Nunnsy Well, I must agree their solution was nicer :)